Pandas: How do I use a function with groupby on multiple columns when the function depends on sequential rows within each group?
I would like to impute some missing values in a pandas data frame using .bfill() or .ffill().  I want to use .groupby() first.  The problem is that .bfill() and .ffill() depend on previous or next rows and I am using .groupby() on multiple columns.
Here is a MWE with what I tried:
import pandas as pd

data = [['Joe Biden', 'a', '2021-10-31', 43],
        ['Donald Trump', 'lv', '2021-10-31', 42],
        ['Joe Biden', 'lv', '2021-10-31', 41],
        ['Joe Biden', 'lv', '2021-11-01', ],
        ['Joe Biden', 'rv', '2021-11-01', 42.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['candidate', 'pop', 'date', 'avg'])

df['avg'] = df.groupby(['candidate', 'pop', 'date'])['avg'].transform(lambda x: x.bfill())

What I want to happen is that the NaN becomes a 41, the 'avg' value for 'Joe Biden', 'lv', on the previous date, '2021-10-31', within the group.
But it's hard to tell what to expect because .bfill() should look at the previous row within the group -- since I have grouped by multiple columns, is it the previous 'candidate', the previous 'pop', or the previous 'date'?  I want it to be the previous 'date'.
The result of the above code is that nothing gets imputed.  Is there a (quicker, if possible) way to do what I'm trying to do?
(If I can get this to work then I also want to do something similar with a rolling average of 'avg' within those same groups.)

Probably suggest to not use political figures' names in your code. This might cause controversy. Just my two cents.

If I am understanding correctly, the grouping is candidate, pop. But you should sort within the grouping by date and then take the avg value from the previous row. So here is my interpretation:
import pandas as pd

data = [['Joe Biden', 'a', '2021-10-31', 43],
        ['Donald Trump', 'lv', '2021-10-31', 42],
        ['Joe Biden', 'lv', '2021-10-31', 41],
        ['Joe Biden', 'lv', '2021-11-01', ],
        ['Joe Biden', 'rv', '2021-11-01', 42.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['candidate', 'pop', 'date', 'avg'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # convert to datetime for sorting operation
df = df.sort_values(['candidate', 'pop', 'date'])  # sort by candidate, pop, and date 
df['avg'] = df.groupby(['candidate', 'pop'])['avg'].ffill() # use forward fill since the date is now sorted ascending


Why didn't I think to do this?  Worked exactly as I wanted, thanks!
